# How to measure the compactness of a set of points

Tags: density

I'm looking for ideas on how to measure the compactness of a set of points. The idea is similar to identifying clusters, but instead I want to compare two distinct sets of points and return a measure of how compact one set is compared to the other.

So far the only research I've come across is specific to finding clusters within a set, rather than measuring the whole set.

Can anyone point me to useful algorithms for accomplishing this? In particular, it would be great to find an existing tool in QGIS that does this, although that's not necessary.

Comment: How about something like the CEP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_error_probable? Among other applications, it's used for assessing the accuracy of GPS devices (clusters of readings (points)) to determine positional accuracy wthin a calculated radius 95% of the time. This approach could be used to determine 50% or 95%, etc. of your points are within a circle with a radius of 10 meters compared to another cluster where 95% of the points are within a 5 meter radius.

Comment: you can also produce a kernel density layer and compare the values for the two clusters. The kernel density of course will be calculated relative to the whole set, so values will change as you change the set of points used to calculate your kernel density surface. There is a tool in ArcGIS for it I am not sure in QGIS, but I'd assume there would be an equivalent.

Comment: Try creating Thiessen polygons. More compact Set of points should show another area distribution then less compact or uniformly spaced sets.

Comment: Points count divided by the area of their convex hull

Comment: Average of distance matrix is better. Remark above will make points on the line the most compacted crowd